# Rotate two links with Bitly API?

Tags: php, database, function, api, redirect

The intention is to split Ad revenue between two partners, use the same "link offer" and in the back-end rotate two URLs.

The product is the same and both URLs will divide the revenue.

In practice, if someone clicks the "link offer" through social media:

1. The **first link** will be selected and the visitor will continue through that route.
2. A second visitor will go through the **second link**
3. And a **third** visitor will be back to link number one. An so forth.

In that case we will always split the revenue (50/50).

Is it possible to make Bitly API do this through a php file hosted on my site which would act as the re-director for both URLs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do this.  Making a redirector is easy. You should realize that your site will be getting several requests at the same time. The way I would go about doing this is to generate a random number and use modulo 2 to go to url 1 or url 2 on average.

```
$n = mt_rand(time());
if ( $n % 2 == 0 ) {
    // do url 1
}
else {
    // do url 2
}
```

Comment: It has to be 50/50. Random is not exactly equal.

Comment: If you attempt to force it to be exactly 50/50, you will end up with a processing bottleneck. What would happen if 25 requests came in at the same time?  You will not be able to say "the previous one was 1, so this one is 2". There would be no previous.

Comment: That is unfortunate, I did not forsee a bottleneck, how about Bitly's API can it manage several requests and make a selector?

Comment: I do not know the bitly API. I would think they would have the same issue. If you do not anticipate a huge amount of traffic, you can use a database table (auto increment) to control which one to use.